# Manually Activate/Deactivate SnapLines For Custom Controls

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

At this point, I almost never want to design a control with rich design-time support again. That said...

I am already overriding the `SnapLines` property in my `ControlDesigner`-derived class to manually forward out various snaplines from the child controls of my control -- the text baseline (pink) snap from the labels and comboboxes; the text inset snap from the labels; the top, bottom, left and right snaplines from the comboboxes. Those snaplines activate when the control itself is moved around on the form and when other controls are moved around it.

What I need is the ability to tell the designer to activate the snaplines and then deactivate them while I'm doing an internal move or resize of the underlying controls.

My comboboxes are resizable through overrides of `OnMouseDragBegin`, `OnMouseDragMove`, and `OnMouseDragEnd` in my control designer. The magic bullet I'm looking for is something I can call in Begin to tell the designer to show the snaplines and something in End to tell it to stop.

Allowing people to resize and move the internal controls at design time is kind of useless if they don't show snaplines for each other or for external controls.

As with stuff like this, it's incredibly hard to search for. I've found one post on a forum where someone asked this exact question that had (of course) no responses. That's about it.

Obviously the issue of actually *snapping* to the snaplines when/if they're shown remains. Just being able to see them would be a nice start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you want todo is to create a Design Surface [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designsurface.aspx)

I've used this to create my own design surface for my application so that the clients can customize the forms.

Hope this helps,

Johan J v Rensburg

Comment: While I'm not sure if this is the _correct_ answer, I do know it's the only one that said something that I haven't run into in my own investigation. With apology for the long time I've waited for other answers, I will mark this as the one. Thanks, Johan.